# Postgres Set column default value as empty

Tags: postgresql

How can I set a default empty value when I create a column? The table `workflow_job_template_id` is a INTEGER type and should be empty by default.

How come other tables have `DEFAULT NOT NULL` but no value? I want the new column to be NOT NULL but empty in the default value.

```
ALTER TABLE main_workflowjobnode 
  ADD COLUMN "workflow_job_template_id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT='';

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "="
LINE 2: ...LUMN "workflow_job_template_id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT='';
```

Here is the table structure:

```
                                                                  Table "public.main_workflowjobnode"
          Column           |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                     Default                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                        | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('main_workflowjobnode_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 created                   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                                  | plain    |              |
 modified                  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                                  | plain    |              |
 job_id                    | integer                  |           |          |                                                  | plain    |              |
 unified_job_template_id   | integer                  |           |          |                                                  | plain    |              |
 workflow_job_id           | integer                  |           |          |                                                  | plain    |              |
 char_prompts              | text                     |           | not null |                                                  | extended |              |
 inventory_id              | integer                  |           |          |                                                  | plain    |              |
 ancestor_artifacts        | text                     |           | not null |                                                  | extended |              |
 extra_data                | text                     |           | not null |                                                  | extended |              |
 survey_passwords          | text                     |           | not null |                                                  | extended |              |
 do_not_run                | boolean                  |           | not null |                                                  | plain    |              |
 all_parents_must_converge | boolean                  |           | not null |                                                  | plain    |              |
 identifier                | character varying(512)   |           | not null |                                                  | extended |              |
```

Comment: An empty strings isn't a valid number. If you want some kind of not-null default, then use e.g. `0`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the not null condition and setting it NULL by default

Comment: how is that the other columns have empty value and set NOT NULL?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just using the `NULL` value to represent "missing" in your `workflow_job_template_id` column.  `NULL` semantically means "unknown" in the SQL language.  What you are currently trying to do is not even valid:

```sql
ALTER TABLE main_workflowjobnode 
    ADD COLUMN "workflow_job_template_id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT = '';
```

This isn't valid because an integer column cannot store a string, including empty string, as a value.

Comment: how is that the other columns have empty value and set NOT NULL?

Comment: I can't see your actual data, but AFAIK it should not be possible to insert a record into your table where, for some non nullable integer column, the integer value is not specified or missing from the insert.